# unexpected "ed25519-nkey" algorithm error when using NAS and NSC of NATS.io

Tags: jwt, nats.io

A team I'm working with, has created a NAS Docker container. The Dockerfile uses `FROM synadia/nats-account-server:0.8.4` and installs NSC using `curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nats-io/nsc/master/install.py | python`. When NAS is run in the Docker container, it is given a path to a `server.conf` file that contains `operatorjwtpath: "/nsc/accounts/nats/OperatorName/OperatorName.jwt"`.

The problem is, that when I generate the operator on my PC using `nsc add operator -i` and when I run the Docker container on AWS Fargate and mount the JWT file to the appropriate folder using an AWS EFS filesystem, the container crashes and shows the error `unexpected "ed25519-nkey" algorithm`.

According to the NATS [basics page](https://docs.nats.io/nats-tools/nsc/basics), the algorithm that should be used is `"alg": "ed25519"`. But when I generated the JWT and decoded it on [this site](https://jwt.io/), I see that what's being used is `"alg": "ed25519-nkey"`.

So what is going on here? I can't find any specific info about an algorithm that has the "nkey" appended to its name. This is the default JWT that's generated. Why is it different from what the NAS algorithm expects? How do I solve this error?

*Extra info: According to [this site](https://synadia.com/ngs/signup), it's supposed to be due to a version conflict, but even upgrading to `FROM synadia/nats-account-server:1.0.0` didn't solve it.*

Comment: For now, the problem went away when I purged all builds of the Docker container and started afresh with NAS 1.0.0. Now the error shown is "support for direct access of the nsc folder has been removed. use a dedicated store directory and specify the operator jwt path instead".